# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I dont know why meantime i compile my query in linq as follows below

```
from c in PriceListPolicies_TBLs
where ((c.CountryCode ?? "VNALL")== "VNALL" ? "VN" : c.CountryCode || 
      (c.CountryCode ?? "THALL") == "THALL" ? "TH" : c.CountryCode) 
select c
```

gives this error

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'

how can I get this query to work?

Comment: I can't think of any way how this condition would make sense. You can't say `where (someString1 || someString2)`. Please explain what you want to query.

Comment: @cremor hi, i just want in case the field CountryCode from database contain the data as "VNALL" and "THALL" then should show on the datagrid the abbrevation  as "VN" and "TH" it is the result i wish .Hope  you understand .Thansk anyway

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
from c in PriceListPolicies_TBLs 
where 
(
  ((c.CountryCode ?? "VNALL") == "VNALL" ? "VN" : c.CountryCode)
  || 
  ((c.CountryCode ?? "THALL") == "THALL" ? "TH" : c.CountryCode)
) 
select c
```

Comment: @sll thanks Sll i tried to appply your code but appear this error :Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' ...i am trying to work out this ine.Thanks so much

Comment: This condition doesn't make sense. You are basically writing `where (someString1 || someString2)`

Comment: this is an other question, please add your answer

Comment: Because it is wrong, as I explained it and JayJay showed by the compiler error it produces.

Answer (score 3):

The `||` operator can only be applied to `bool` and `bool`

```
c.CountryCode || (c.CountryCode ?? "THALL") // is wrong, since c.CountryCode is a string
```

Comment: You completely ripped that part out of context. While this really is the offending part of the code, you don't seem to understand what the OP actually tried to do. See sll's answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999150/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-and-bool#comment21070841_14999150) you don't want a condition. Simply do something like this:

```
var allItems = from c in PriceListPolicies_TBLs
               select c;

foreach (var c in allItems)
{
    if (c.CountryCode == "VNALL")
    {
        c.CountryCode = "VN";
    }
    else if (c.CountryCode == "THALL")
    {
        c.CountryCode = "TH";
    }
}
```